# alternative approaches to analyze behavioral data

Tags: mixed-model

I'm new in this community and, I admit, I'm not a super expert on statistics. Thus, I'm sorry if my issue could seem silly. This is the situation: I tested 3 groups of people (children, youngs and olds) that were involved in a computerized task where reaction times and accuracy level were collected. I'm focusing on a particular set of cognitive processes (executive functions) that present a U-Shaped during the lifespan (lower performance in children and olds than youngs). I'd like to analyze data by a different approach than most conventional NHST. What do you suggest? Are mixed models appropriated in my case, considering that executive functions don't respect the assumption of linearity?
Thank you,
Fabio

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do something other than NHST?  After the omnibus you can conduct two post hoc tests or a polynomial trend to establish a U-shaped pattern. What is your statistical hypothesis?

Comment: Thank your Heitz for your tips. I've tried to implement a polynomial regression and it fits my data better than a linear regression (as expected).